# Comando do compilador GCC para exibir #ifdef

Tags: c, c++, debug, gcc

Qual o comando do compilador uso para exibir essa linha em tempo de execução?

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    double tInicio_=clock() ;
#endif
```

Comment: Não entendi o que deseja, o seu código não está executando isto e deseja que o corra? Está compilando como *debug*? Dê mais contexto à pergunta.

Comment: Isso, preciso saber como compilo ele e executo de modo a mostrar essa linha, sei que tem um comando próprio pra isso, só conheço o de compilar: gcc <arquivo>.c -o <arquivo>.exe -lm e o de executar: ./<arquivo>.exe

Comment: @ThiagoPrestes se a resposta dada resolveu, você pode clicar no V verdinho do lado dela para marcar como aceita e como resolvido.

Comment: @ThiagoPrestes A resposta postada resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução apresentada foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que ela é satisfatória. Também pode votar em toda e qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo. Aceitar e votar são coisas distintas.

Answer (score 6):

É só usar a [diretiva `-D` na linha de comando do GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html):

```
-D DEBUG
```

Isso criará uma definição de `DEBUG` que fará este `#ifdef` ser compilado e portanto executará quando a aplicação for chamada (claro, depende de onde isto for usado). Isso está ligando essa "variável", então ela existindo faz o `ifdef` ser verdadeiro.

Outras coisas precisam estar certas no código para funcionar, mas isso não tem como saber pela pergunta.

Comment: Opa, era isso mesmo que eu queria saber, muito obrigado, estou usando ele no fim do código, não está dentro de outro condicional, portanto, vai executar de qualquer forma. VLW mesmo em!!